# union result of multiple dynamic queries sql

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, cursor

I have two tables tblJobs and tblJobseeker. 
tblJobs

```
JobId  skill     location
  5  .net, php    Mexico
  8   java        Boston
  9   sql, c++  London, Mexico
```

tblJobseeker

```
ID   skill       location
 3   .net         Mexico
 7    sql         Boston
 10   java        Boston
 12   php         Mexico
 13   c++         London, Boston
```

Now I want to loop through first table `tblJobs` and find matching Jobseeker based on `skill` and `location`. For each record in `tblJobs` a result will come which I need to union with other records result set. I was trying to use cursor and dynamic query but how I can set condition of column `skill` and `location` in dynamic query. Also the records in both tables may vary

In above case, result should be

```
ID   skill       location
 3   .net         Mexico
 12   php         Mexico
 10   java        Boston
 13   c++        London, Boston
```

I have edited the question. Here I am using charindex to match the result and inner join is not possible.There can be n number of locations or skills so different columns are not possible.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using

Comment: add expected result too.

Comment: *which I need to union with other records result set.* What other records?

Comment: Its important what you tried, sample data and output ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple inner join would do:

```
select s.* 
from tblJobseeker s 
inner join tblJobs j
on s.skill = j.skill
and s.location = j.location;
```

Comment: Hi Gurwinder, since a record can contain multiple skills therefore inner join will not help

Comment: In that case you need to normalize your data. It should atleast conform to 1NF. Having comma separated values in a cell is bad practice

Comment: I know but skills or locations can be multiple and of any numbers